# Vue2 generated select triggers event for every other selects

Tags: vue.js, select, input, buefy

I have a Vue2 project with Buefy extension. Then I have an array of objects which is rendered in the template with one select component for each item. Everything works, but if I trigger @input event on one of the select elements it triggers input event for all selects in the list. I dont understand what is wrong with that.

```
    <div v-for="(inv, index) in pendingInvitations" :key="index" class="columns is-desktop">
        <div class="column is-4">{{inv.email}}</div>
        <div class="column is-4">
            <b-field class="mb-5">
                <b-select v-if="invitationRoles" 
                          :input="changeInvitationRole(index)" 
                          v-model="pendingInvitations[index].role" 
                          :placeholder="role">
                    <option v-for="(value, key) in invitationRoles"
                            :key="key"
                            :value="value">
                        {{ value }}
                    </option>
                </b-select>
            </b-field>
        </div>
    </div>

    ...

    changeInvitationRole(index){
        console.log(index);
    },
```

If I change the role and there are three items in the list the console.log() writes 0, 1, 2 as indexes for all items. Why it happens to me? I expect only current itmes index in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing **input** with **change**

Comment: :) this time the solution was to use @input.native as you wrote before. Change the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: But I have stil the problem with input cause it sends me the old value of the object in event handler. Dont understand. The handler have access to the old value.